# phone 8 hyperlink button style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

is there any good example for hyperlinkButton style
I found the one below but in pressed state I get error and my hyperlinkButton is 2 lines and if I dont use this style I get 2 underlines for the 2 lines but if I use the style only the last line gets underlined
what I want from style is I getm both lines underlined and when clicked foreground changes color to white instead of phone accent color
here is the style

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                 Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                                 Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: "is there any good example for hyperlinkButton style" yes lots. but I'm guessing you actually want to do a specific thing. What are you specifically trying to do or having problems with?

Comment: in the style I wrote above the hyperlink is 
-only underlined 1 line but I have 2 lines (I used "&#x0a;" in content for break line.
-if pressed state is written like that I get system error > HyperlinkStyle.DLL!HyperlinkStyle.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line... C#
I want my style to underline both lines and changes the text color when pressed to a color that I set